# False logic argument

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have to proof the following theorem $$(w ⇒ p ∨ s) ∧ (t ∧ p ⇒ r) ⇒ (t ∧ ¬ r ⇒ ¬ q)$$

Using the assumptions, I would like to proof that $(t∧p⇒r)⇒(t∧¬r⇒¬q)$, but I got only $(p⇒r)⇒(t∧¬r⇒¬q)$. I thought I could use $(t∧p⇒r) ⇒ (p⇒r)$, but it seems to be false. How can I modify/finish this proof?

The answer of @DonAntonio is great, but I can't work with this. I would need a complete, linear proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will gently disagree with DonAntonio: a linear proof does not have to be long and tiring, but it may very well be the way you do it (no offense, Leo!).

### Your proof

First, let me address your proof. You need to make coarser steps. I don't know what class you're in (it looks like you are using perhaps a Gries and Schneider text), but please don't use contrapositive to turn $p \Rightarrow \neg q$ into $\neg\neg q \Rightarrow \neg p$ and then a separate step to replace $\neg\neg q$ with $q$. It is fine to have one form of contrapositive be simply: $p \Rightarrow \neg q \ \equiv \ q \Rightarrow \neg p$.

A similar comment applies to the steps of your calculation where you replace $s \Rightarrow \neg t$ with $\bf true$, then commute $\bf true$ to the other side of the formula for some reason, then eliminate it using the identity property of $\wedge$. This level of detail is not appropriate for the complexity of proof we are dealing with here.

If we clean up that mess, here is your calculation:

$\quad t \wedge \neg r \;\Rightarrow\; \neg q$

$\Leftarrow \quad \{$ using $q \Rightarrow s \vee p$ and monotonicity $\}$

$\quad t \wedge \neg r \ \Rightarrow \ \neg(s \vee p)$

$\equiv \quad \{$ de Morgan $\}$

$\quad t \wedge \neg r \ \Rightarrow \ \neg s \wedge \neg p$

$\Leftarrow \quad \{$ monotonicity $\}$

$\quad (t \Rightarrow \neg s) \;\wedge\; (\neg r \Rightarrow \neg p)$

$\equiv \quad \{$ contrapositive, twice $\}$

$\quad (s \Rightarrow \neg t) \;\wedge\; (p \Rightarrow r)$

$\equiv \quad \{$ using $s \Rightarrow \neg t$ $\}$

$\quad p \Rightarrow r$

The problem is, we only have $t \wedge p \Rightarrow r$, which is weaker than $p \Rightarrow r$, so this proof is simply not viable. The reason it is not is because of the third step, where you strengthened the calculandum into something too strong to prove.

My general suggestion to you is to be more careful with strengthening steps, and only use equivalence where possible.

### A different approach

If you are calculating with booleans or anything else, there is a certain trade-off you have to be aware of. Either you do some work to "clean up" the given formulae, or you will have to do that work while calculating.

To be more specific, let me label the formulae in question:

$(0) \quad q \,\Rightarrow\, s \vee p$

$(1) \quad s \Rightarrow \neg t$

$(2) \quad t \wedge p \,\Rightarrow\, r$

$(3) \quad t \wedge \neg r \,\Rightarrow\, \neg q \quad.$

Now, if I don't wish to do any work up front, I might try to prove $(3)$ by strengthening $\neg q$ into $t \wedge \neg r$:

$\quad \neg q$

$\Leftarrow \quad \{$ using $(0)$ and antimonotonicity $\}$

$\quad \neg (s \vee p)$

$\equiv \quad \{$ de Morgan $\}$

$\quad \neg s \wedge \neg p$

$\Leftarrow \quad \{$ using $(1)$ and antimonotonicity $\}$

$\quad t \wedge \neg p$

$\Leftarrow \quad \{$ using $(2)$ in the form $t \wedge \neg r \,\Rightarrow\, \neg p$ and monotonicity $\}$

$\quad t \wedge t \wedge \neg r$

$\equiv \quad \{$ idempotence $\}$

$\quad t \wedge \neg r$

Personally, I think this is a bad proof: too much work is crammed into each step.

### Cleaning up the givens

My taste is to instead do some work up front to clean up the given formulae. First, I use the contrapositive to rewrite $(3)$ as the equivalent:

$(3') \quad t \wedge q \,\Rightarrow\, r \quad.$

Given the shape of $(2)$:

$(2) \hphantom{'} \quad t \wedge p \,\Rightarrow\, r \quad,$

this suggests that we try to prove $(3')$ by strengthening $r$ into $t \wedge q$. We start as follows:

$\quad r$

$\Leftarrow \quad \{ \ (2) \ \}$

$\quad t \wedge p \quad.$

Now we need to strengthen $p$, so we rearrange $(0)$ as the equivalent:

$(0') \quad q \wedge \neg s \,\Rightarrow\, p \quad.$

Thus we can continue our calculation:

$\quad r$

$\Leftarrow \quad \{ \ (2) \ \}$

$\quad t \wedge p$

$\Leftarrow \quad \{ \ (0') \ \}$

$\quad t \wedge q \wedge \neg s \quad.$

Finally, we need to strengthen $\neg s$ so we rewrite $(1)$ as the equivalent:

$(1') \quad t \Rightarrow \neg s \quad,$

and finish the calculation as follows:

$\quad r$

$\Leftarrow \quad \{ \ (2) \ \}$

$\quad t \wedge p$

$\Leftarrow \quad \{ \ (0') \ \}$

$\quad t \wedge q \wedge \neg s$

$\Leftarrow \quad \{ \ (1') \ \}$

$\quad t \wedge q \wedge t$

$\equiv \quad \{$ idempotence $\}$

$\quad t \wedge q \quad.$

The cleanliness and clarity of each step suggests that this was a nice rewriting of the givens. We simply used shunting and contraposition to rewrite everything compatibly. For reference, we used the equations in the following forms:

$(0') \quad q \wedge \neg s \,\Rightarrow\, p$

$(1') \quad t \Rightarrow \neg s$

$(2) \hphantom{'} \quad t \wedge p \,\Rightarrow\, r$

$(3') \quad t \wedge q \,\Rightarrow\, r \quad.$

Note that because of the shape of $(1)$, it was inevitable that one of our symbols would need to be negated. In our case, we used $\neg s$. However, note that we never used $s$ without the negation symbol. Thus, letting $S = \neg s$ we could write everything as:

$(0') \quad q \wedge S \,\Rightarrow\, p$

$(1') \quad t \Rightarrow S$

$(2) \hphantom{'} \quad t \wedge p \,\Rightarrow\, r$

$(3') \quad t \wedge q \,\Rightarrow\, r \quad,$

and see that, by doing the work up front, negation no longer has anything to do with the structure of our argument.

### The moral

The moral of the story here is that in any field of mathematical inquiry, it is important to massage our symbols and concepts so they are compatible with each other. Perhaps this is a simple problem from logic, but with a mess of symbols in front of you, even that simple problem confused you. How can we hope to prove complicated theorems in algebra, analysis, etc, if we can't even neatly tackle simple problems?

Be clean, be organized. It's no guarantee of a proof but it's the best we can do.

### Appendix

If you are working in a rigid framework that doesn't allow you to do this sort of "cleaning" work up front, here is an alternate, "wide" calculation using the original formulae:

$(0) \quad q \,\Rightarrow\, s \vee p$

$(1) \quad s \Rightarrow \neg t$

$(2) \quad t \wedge p \,\Rightarrow\, r$

$(3) \quad t \wedge \neg r \,\Rightarrow\, \neg q \quad.$

Here is the calculation of $(3)$:

$\quad t \wedge \neg r \,\Rightarrow\, \neg q$

$\Leftarrow \quad \{$ using $(2)$ and $(0)$ and monotonicity $\}$

$\quad t \wedge \neg(t \wedge p) \,\Rightarrow\, \neg(s \vee p)$

$\equiv \quad \{$ de Morgan, twice $\}$

$\quad t \wedge (\neg t \vee \neg p) \,\Rightarrow\, \neg s \wedge \neg p$

$\equiv \quad \{$ absorption on the left side $\}$

$\quad t \wedge \neg p \,\Rightarrow\, \neg s \wedge \neg p$

$\Leftarrow \quad \{$ monotonicity of $\wedge$ $\}$

$\quad t \Rightarrow \neg s$

$\equiv \quad \{$ contrapositive $\}$

$\quad s \Rightarrow \neg t$

$\equiv \quad \{ \ (1) \ \}$

$\quad {\bf true} \quad.$

To clarify, I don't endorse this sort of calculation, generally speaking!

Comment: Your answer is very clear! Can you just develop $t∧¬(t∧p)⇒¬(s∨p)$ in the Appendix?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Do you not see the rest of the calculation? De Morgan, etc?

Comment: It is because there is several monotonicity  rules. I am not sure which one your used. The remaining proof is clear, but I can't see how you develop $t∧¬(t∧p)⇒¬(s∨p)$?

Comment: In the first step I use the antimonotonicity of ¬ (twice), the antimonotonicity of => in its left argument, and the monotonicity of => in its right argument. In the fourth step I use the monotonicity of /\. (All of these monotonicities are with respect to =>.)

Comment: I can't use the antimonotonicity of $¬$ because I have not seen it yet. If you can use a work around, it might be very useful.

Comment: The way I understand that first step in my mind is "by strengthening r, I weaken ¬r and the antecedent, which strengthens the implication". And: "by weakening q, I strengthen ¬q, the consequent, which strengthens the implication". (Actually in my head I'm just saying "stronger, weaker, stronger", and "weaker, stronger, stronger" or something like that.)

Comment: Then prove it and submit it to your teacher.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120543/discussion-between-jeremy-weissmann-and-leo).

Comment: @Leo, I don't see you in the chat. If you come there I can help further.

Answer (score 2):

Shorter and probably  simpler proof by reductio ad absurdum: suppose that isn't true that $\;(t\wedge\neg r)\rightarrow\neg q\;$ . Then it must be that $\;t\wedge\neg r=T\;$  and $\;\neg q=F\iff q= T \;$ , and both $\;t=T\,,\,\neg r= T\iff r=F\;$

But then, since $\;(t\wedge p)\rightarrow r=T\;$ (assumption given), it must be that $\;t\wedge p=F\;$ . Since $\;t=T\;$ , this means that it must be $\;p=F\;$.

Also, we have the assumption $\;s\rightarrow\neg t=T\;$ . But $\;\neg t=F\;$ , so it must be that also $\;s=F\;$.

And we then get our contradiction with the first assumption, since $\;q=T\;$ yet $\;s\vee p=F\;$ as both $\;s= p= F\;$ .

Comment: Can you build a linear proof as I did?

Comment: @Leo I probably can but I won't. It is way too long and tiring, and it is a pitty to waste that  much time when we can do it way faster and simpler.

Comment: @DonAntonio The only "problem" with you argument is that there is no way to teach someone else how you designed it. It is just an instinct which you have developed undoubtedly by having spent a lot of time with formulas like this. Plus, there are no larger morals to take away from the exercise — the only reason to do logic is to develop some sensibilities that you can carry into actual mathematical work.

Comment: @DonAntonio As long as we want to substitute variables, why not just assume t? Then our givens reduce to q => s \/ p, ¬s, p => r, and the theorem to be proved reduces to ¬r => ¬q.  From ¬s, the first given reduces to q => p, which with p => r gives q => r, which is the contrapositive of our goal. (Of course, if ¬t then the demonstrandum is vacuously true.)

Comment: @JeremyWeissmann No "instinct" at all. It is a perfectly well based way to prove stuff in mathematics: assume the conclusion is false, develope this assumption and reach a contradiction. By the excluded third principle, this means your assumption (i.e., that the conclusion is false) is incorrect, ergo: the conclusion must follow.. Either the OP already studied this or else (s)he didn't, but every step in the reasoning is shown above

Comment: And no, I don't want to substitute variables at all: I just deduced what the truth values of the different parts (which I don't know, and I don't care either, if they're atoms or whole, long propositions or well formed formulae) and with them I reached a contradiction. That's all.

Comment: Assuming the conclusion is false is in essence no different than assuming t is true. We both made case analysis where one case is trivial. And in both of our approaches, there is an art to following the path of truth values to arrive at the contradiction — which can arrive anywhere. At least when you try to design a directed proof you know where you're headed from and where you're headed to.

Comment: I'm not saying there is anything wrong with your argument, by the way! It is absolutely correct and I didn't mean to imply otherwise.

Comment: @JeremyWeissmann No, I don't think so. Assuming the conclusion is false *is the way* to go to do a reductio ad absurdum proof. Of course, one can assume anything about whatever one wants, but for the kind of proofs I presented it must be done that way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120541/discussion-between-jeremy-weissmann-and-donantonio).

Comment: @JeremyWeissmann Neither I thought or implied you implied my proof is wrong. I just referred to what you say about " The only "problem" with you argument is that there is no way to teach someone else how you designed it. It is just an instinct which you have developed...:. No, it is not an instinct, though there is some instinct in "guessing" where thecontradiction will pop up. In this case, for example, I din't know beforehand where will I get a contradiction...but again it is a very simple case, too.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I meant — sorry for not being more clear. I followed up a bit in chat with you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm putting my second reply to @DonAntonio into its own answer. If we take a substitution-of-values approach, the ideal candidate to me seems to be to assume $t$ — that is, to let $t = \bf true$.

Then our givens reduce to:

- $q \,\Rightarrow\, s \vee p$
- $\neg s \quad$ (that is, $s = \bf false$)
- $p \Rightarrow r$

and our demonstrandum reduces to:

- $\neg r \Rightarrow \neg q \quad.$

But from $s = \bf false$, the first given reduces to $q \Rightarrow p$, which in combination with $p \Rightarrow r$ yields $q \Rightarrow r$, which is just the contrapositive of what we're trying to show.

Of course, if $\neg t$ then our demonstrandum is vacuously true. (This was the reason we chose to perform a case analysis on $t$.) So the theorem is proved in any case.